# EF 6: Code First Mapping to stored procedures: Passing Table-Valued Parameter

Tags: entity-framework-6

In EF 6 using Code First when I attempt to map a stored procedure to an entity, I'm receiving a complier error message CS0453: The type 'Type Name' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'Parameter Name' in the generic type or method 'Generic Identifier' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsdhc71f(v=vs.90).aspx).

The cause of the error is a data table I'm trying to pass to the stored procedure.  The stored procedure is expecting a table-valued parameter (tvp).

How can I pass a TVP to the stored procedure using EF 6 CF fluent mappings?

Thanks

marc

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does not support Table Valued Parameters.